# Linux - timeout on disconnected send

Tags: linux, sockets, send, blocking, disconnect

I'm developing server application and have following problem with sending data back to client, that suddenly terminates the connection.

When I call `send` on blocking socket with write timeout set via `setsockopt(SO_SNDTIMEO)` and client disconnects during sending (i.e a few bytes are sent, then client properly terminates TCP - as can be seen in wireshark), `send` still blocks, until send timeout elapses. Following call to `send` returns error as expected.

I would expect that TCP termination (FIN/ACK) will cause blocking `send` to return immediately, not after timeout.

Have someone ever seen such behaviour? Is it normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the FIN sent from the client does not unblock the `send()` at the server. When the client calls `close()` the FIN is sent to server and the connection is closed for the direction from client to server. The direction from server to client is still open till the server calls `close()` and FIN is sent to the client.

When the client sends FIN and the server sends ACK back then connection on server is in the *CLOSE_WAIT* state and the connection on client is in the *FIN_WAIT_2* state. Server still may send data and client still may receive data till server close the connection.

The close connection cannot be detected through `send()`. Only `recv()` detects the connection closed by peer.

If your code must execute an immediate action when client close the connection then it must call `poll()` or `select()` and use non-blocking `send()` and `recv()` calls.